# Screw on tub overflow gasket?

Tags: bathtub, overflow

Help! I was replacing my overflow cover when I realized the overflow pipe is missing it's gasket. This is a brass pipe with machined threads on the outside. The top of the overflow very slightly peeks into the tub (see pics)

I noticed some disintegrated plastic around the thread, so something was screwed on at one point. The local plumbing supply couldn't figure it out, and I can't find anything online.

[image]

[image]

Comment: In my experience the gasket is on the outside. You can't see it from this angle...

Comment: I poured a little bit of water into the space between the tub and the pipe and I felt it come out...would you have any idea what type of part I need to fix this? I've seen the standard ones that go in btwn the tub and the pipe like a compression. But don't think that would suffice here...

Comment: Well, yeah  - it would do that - because you've got it all loose... Once you screw the front on tight it's supposed to pull the gasket tight against the back of the bath to seal. [Here's a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=spCeKSwd_No) of a guy replacing the overflow gasket and although his has 2 screws to attach the cover, you can see how it's supposed to work. And you might want to remove all that old sealer from around where the cover goes (and *do not* apply more when you put it back together).

Comment: "disintegrated plastic around the thread" - that was the rubber grommet that goes between (behind) the tub and the drain. Yours has slots for the cover plate screws just like everyone I've ever seen, which you removed, right? Picture of the cover plate?

Comment: @brhans - inside of the wall; 'outside' of the tub. (I thought you had it backwards. It was just ambiguous)

Comment: The cover plate got destroyed when removed. Do you think this is what needs to go back there: LASCO 02-3027 Bathtub Sponge Gasket for Waste And Overflow Plate https://www.amazon.com/dp/B000FH6GME/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_apa_i_ji4pEbJNJ3T98

Comment: I've never seen one with a throat like that. Also it's <cough> *not local*. The one for $40 looks better but I'd just get w/e they have at your store and return it if it doesn't fit; they should be pretty standard. Really, the question is, what's up with those threads on the outside? IDK: wild goose chase I think.